# Objective C - Recording Audio Stream

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I'm looking for a solution to record an audio stream to a file. I can get audio to play but I'm struggling to figure out how to record/save to file what is playing.

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Player code thus far:

```
@interface ViewControllerPlayer ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerPlayer

@synthesize receivedStreamReferenceNumber;

- (void)convertData:(NSData *) data {
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
    [self loadPlayer:url];
}

- (void) loadPlayer:(NSURL *) url {
    audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    [audioPlayer play];
}

- (void) start {
    NSLog(@"%@", receivedStreamReferenceNumber);
    NSString *urlHalf = @"http://getstreamurl.php?KeyRef=";
    NSMutableString *mutableUrlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlHalf, receivedStreamReferenceNumber];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: mutableUrlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self convertData:data];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self start];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

EDIT:

I've incorporated the following code... but i'm struggling to tie it all together. The following should create a file that the recorded stream audio is saved to. I suppose i've got to tell the AVRecorder to listen to the AVPlayer some how? Again -- help will be greatly appreciated:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [playButton setEnabled:YES];

    // Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"xxx.mp3",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];


    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

Comment: Hi -- i've been taking a look at AVRecorder... but i'm not sure how to implement it so that I can both hear the audio stream AND record at the same time. Any help is greatly appreciated.